# Change timestamp PHP format to Dutch

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm busy with a date notation in Dutch but I can't get this fixed.
The data is retrieved from the database (change data timestamp).

```
<td >
 <span style="font-size:10px"><br/>
   Gegevens bijgewerkt op: <?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); 
    echo date_with_weekday($item->stamp);?>
 </span>
</td>
```

I've set the locale to Dutch and the database table stamp `($item->stamp)` is also retrieved. However, January should be januari. February to februari, etc, etc).

How can I set this?

Here is the code from the PHP file:

```
<?php
    function seprator_heading($heading){
        return '<tr><td colspan="2" class="seprator_head">'.$heading.'</td></tr>';
}

function date_formate($dt){
    return ($dt!='')?date('d/m/Y',strtotime($dt)):'';
}
function age($dt){
    if($dt!='' && $dt!='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){
        $birthdt=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dt));
        list($d,$m,$y)=split('-',$birthdt);
        $age=(date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$y)-1):(date("Y")-$y));
        return $age;
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}
function date_with_weekday($dt){
    $date=($dt!='' && $dt!='0000-00-00 00:00:00')?date('l, d F Y G:i',strtotime($dt)):'';
    if($date!=''){
        list($day,$dtime)=split(',',$date);
        return dutch_weekdays($day).' '.$dtime;
    }else{
        return ' - ';
    }
}
function dutch_weekdays($d){
    if(!empty($d)){
        switch(strtolower($d)){
        case 'monday':
            return 'maandag';
            break;
        case 'tuesday':
            return 'dinsdag';
            break;
        case 'wednesday':
            return 'woensdag';
            break;
        case 'thursday':
            return 'donderdag';
            break;
        case 'friday':
            return 'vrijdag';
            break;
        case 'saturday':
            return 'zaterdag';
            break;
        case 'sunday':
            return 'zondag';
            break;
        }
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}
?>
```

Br,

Steve

Comment: Perhaps if you showed the code for the `date_with_weekday()` function

Comment: Please add code from `date_with_weekday()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the locale aware [`strftime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function in your `date_with_weekday` function.  Example:

```
$timestamp = time();
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y', $timestamp);
// output: zondag, december 29, 2013
```

The constants are available in the [`strftime` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

**Edited to address update from OP**:

IMHO, you're trying too hard to abstract something PHP does really well. Get rid of those date functions and use the PHP date functions. In this case that would be `strftime`, since you need the output to be locale aware.

Comment: Ok, it makes sence but how can I incorporate this within the current pages?

I have a table called tfv_employees within Joomla.
In this table I have a column called "stamp".

I need to show the result after every change made in the database.

In this case I used the code above.

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: If the stamp column is a timestamp, then you can simply pass stamp as the second argument to `strftime`. If 'stamp' is a string in a date format, you should use `strtotime` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to obtain the date's timestamp.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'm going to look into this and try.

Cheers,

Steve